# Android Studio waiting for the debugger to attach

Tags: java, android

I'm searching now for three hours and didn't found any solution...

Things I tried:

- Edit the manifest with the "DEBUG" thing
- Restart
- Enable port in firewall
- Clear cache
- Debug without breakpoints
- Try other emulator device
- Remove emulator device
- Activate "Wait for debug" option in the emulator device

And programming without debugging is sometimes really hard.

I hope someone can help me with this...

Greetz

Comment: So *what is happening* when you try?

Comment: Its not solved the problem... what else?

Comment: You're not understanding me. What exactly is occurring when you try to connect your debugger?

Comment: "waiting for the debugger to attach"

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the ADB tool. Go to Android SDK folder (/platform-tools/) and then run:

**Windows:**

adb.exe kill-server
adb.exe start-server

**Mac & Linux:**

./adb kill-server
./adb start-server